# Unable to store Downloaded file from url in QT 4.8

Tags: c++, qt4.8, qfile, qurl

I am trying to download a xml file using url in QT 4.8. Here is my code for this:-

```
downloadurl::downloadurl(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QNetworkAccessManager GetFileDownloadNetworkManager;
    QNetworkReply *GetFileDownloadNetworkReply;

    QObject::connect(&GetFileDownloadNetworkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(FileDownloadReplyReceived(QNetworkReply*)));
    QObject::connect(&GetFileDownloadNetworkManager, SIGNAL((QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(FileDownloadReplyReceived(QNetworkReply*)));

    QUrl url(QString("MyLinkToDownloadFile"));  
    QNetworkRequest reqpn(url);
    reqpn.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    GetFileDownloadNetworkReply = GetFileDownloadNetworkManager.get(reqpn);
}

downloadurl::~downloadurl()
{

}

void downloadurl::FileDownloadReplyReceived(QNetworkReply *Reply)
{
    if(Reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QFile DownloadedFile("/FlashDisk/ServerTemp/12012.xml");
        if (!DownloadedFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        {
            messageBox.critical(0,"Error","Can't open File");
            return;
        }
        DownloadedFile.write(Reply->readAll());
        DownloadedFile.close();
    }
    Reply->deleteLater();
}
```

My code enters in slot but I can't find created `12012.txt` in `/FlashDisk/ServerTemp/` . please Tell what exactly I am missing here.

Comment: Did you try to save the file to a different path (e.g. somewhere in your `/home`)?

Comment: does the program have permission to write on that folder ?

Comment: I have permission. I am writing some other files on same path

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o:- i cross checked with different path. Nothing changed

Comment: What does `SIGNAL((QNetworkReply*))` do?  Using the `Qt5` signal/slot syntax would have highlighted that error.  Also, `GetFileDownloadNetworkManager` is locally scoped within the `downloadurl` constructor and will, therefore, be destroyed when the constructor returns.

Comment: @G.M. :0 I can check the raw data, file is downloaded properly, but may be problem is with QFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve issue by myself. I have to add `QIODevice::Text` permission in `QFile.open`. Here is my final code:-

```
downloadurl::downloadurl(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QNetworkAccessManager GetFileDownloadNetworkManager;
    QNetworkReply *GetFileDownloadNetworkReply;

    QObject::connect(&GetFileDownloadNetworkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(FileDownloadReplyReceived(QNetworkReply*)));
    QObject::connect(&GetFileDownloadNetworkManager, SIGNAL((QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(FileDownloadReplyReceived(QNetworkReply*)));

    QUrl url(QString("MyLinkToDownloadFile"));  
    QNetworkRequest reqpn(url);
    reqpn.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    GetFileDownloadNetworkReply = GetFileDownloadNetworkManager.get(reqpn);
}

downloadurl::~downloadurl()
{

}

void downloadurl::FileDownloadReplyReceived(QNetworkReply *Reply)
{
    if(Reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QFile DownloadedFile("/FlashDisk/ServerTemp/12012.xml");
        if (!DownloadedFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        {
            messageBox.critical(0,"Error","Can't open File");
            return;
        }
        DownloadedFile.write(Reply->readAll());
        DownloadedFile.close();
    }
    Reply->deleteLater();
}
```